# Email Authentication in ERPNext

Tags: erp, erpnext

Right now When a user Signs up, an email is instantly sent to the user's ID. 
However, I want to first verify the user credentials before sending out the the email. 
What process can I use to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting out of the box to stop the email verification.

The email sent is for email verification, the user will not have any roles unless you assign. You can then disable the user if you don't want the user to sign up.